# Xcode multiple local notification sounds

Tags: debugging, ios5, audio, notifications

I have searched through a lot of forums and no one seems to have the answer. The question being, having multiple sounds for x amount of local notifications set up.

Basically I have an Alarm Object that has multiple attributes (name,repeat,switch,snooze minutes,time... and sound) like most apps available on the app store. I can create multiple alarms with that will fire given a chosen date and snooze....but the sound I select from the tableview options for a given alarm, will always be the last chosen sound for any alarm. example

```
alarm[0] = birds.mp3, time = xx.xx pm
alarm[1] = crazy.mp3, time = xx.xx pm
alarm[2] = sky.mp3, time = xx.xx pm
```

3 alarms created, the alarm with sky.mp3 was the last created alarm with the sky.mp3 tableview item selected....now if alarm[0] fires (given that i chose birds.mp3 as a sound) , it will fire with the sky.mp3 instead....

The problem is driving me in circles, I can't seem to find a solution around this bug, basically what i think is happening is there can't be an array of notifications each having different attributes. somebody willing to help, please enlighten me! any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Please include some code in your question - as it stands, it's really unclear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

For your local notifications you can use `UILocalNotification.soundName` in order to set your notification sound.

For more details please check: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html